# Media queries not working on mobile, meta set

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a problem with media queries not being used on mobile device. This works correctly on the browser, but not on mobile devices (it actually seems to render differently between Lumia 800 and iPhone phones).
I've been through most of the posts with this problem on here, and in most cases people left out the meta tag, but I've already set it in the head of the document;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

This is my mobile CSS file:

```
/* ===== == = === 20em (320px) === = == ===== */

@media screen and (min-width : 20em) {
    .slidercontainer {
        display:none;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 30em) {
}

/* ===== == = === 37.5em (600px) === = == ===== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
}

/* ===== == = === 48em (768px) === = == ===== */

@media only screen and (min-width : 48em) {
    .slidercontainer {
        display:inherit;
    }
}

/* ===== == = === 56.25em (900px) === = == ===== */

@media only screen and (min-width : 56.25em) {
}

/* ===== == = === 68.75em (1100px) === = == ===== */

@media only screen and (min-width : 68.75em) {
    .container {
        width:1200px;
    }

}


/* ===== == = === 81.25em (1300px) === = == ===== */

@media only screen and (min-width : 81.25em) {

}
```

And in the head area I also have the 2 stylesheets included, a default one with the regular CSS and mobile with the .. well, mobile styles :)

```
<link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
```

Comment: If we could see the site it might be helpful. Do you have a link so we can test it on a range of devices?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply! Yes, its http://dev.krummalingur.com/jspiping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the problem it seems, I used to have only

```
<html>
<head>
```

in the header document, but once I changed it to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

it started using the mobile stylesheet as well!
A rookie mistake :)

Thanks everyone for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to detect a device:

```
<link href="css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld"/>
```

Or, you can change it to detect a screen size:

```
<link href="css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"/>
```

You can read more about media types: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it doesnt seem to have changed at all :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this is a CSS media query issue.

Even on desktop you are picking up a horizontall scrollbar below c.1240px.

I think this is related to the `<div class="sidebox">`. If you inspect the site using developer tools (in Chrome) or Firebug you can clearly see that someelements are breaking out of the container.

I suspect this is due to a positioning issue or mixing %-widths with defined px-widths.

Comment: Even if it's breaking out of the containers (which I appreciate you pointing out by the way :)), the .slidercontainer should disappear completely on the mobile versions. Do you reckon the positioning can be affecting that as well?

Comment: It's quite possible. Absolute positioning has it's uses but it's not really recommended for resposive layouts.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this method if you would like or Bootstrap 3 If Mobile First Frame Work

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Hi! I tried this, but it's still the same thing sadly :( It's like the mobile devices don't use the stylesheet at all. This is excellent to have though for future reference! Thanks!